# In $\triangle ABC$ with biggest angle $A$ and smallest angle $C$, if $A=2C$ and $a+c=2b$, find $a:b:c$

Tags: geometry

> In $\triangle ABC$, $A$ is the biggest angle, and $C$ is the smallest angle. Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be the length of the sides that are opposite from $\angle A$, $\angle B$, $\angle C$, respectively. If $\angle A=2\angle C$ and $a+c=2b$, find $a:b:c$.

I have no idea how to start, but Law of Sines/Law of Cosines could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=\frac{b}{\sin(B)}=\frac{c}{\sin(C)}$$

This implies that 
$$\frac{b}{\sin(B)}=\frac{a+c}{\sin(A)+\sin(C)}=\frac{2b}{\sin(A)+\sin(C)}$$

Combine this with 
$$A=2C\\
B=180^\circ -A -C =180^\circ -3C$$
and you can find $C$. From there it is easy

Comment: How do you get from equation 1 to 2?

Comment: @Baker013273213 If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then they are also equal to $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$. This is sometimes called "Derived proportions". If you are not familiar, here is the proof: Let $x= \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$. Then $$a=bx \\c=dx$$ and hence $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{bx+dx}{b+d}=x$$

Comment: Continuing on your progress, 
$\frac{1}{Sin{180-3C}}=\frac{2}{Sin {2C} +Sin {C}$
$\frac{1}{Sin{3C}}=\frac{2}{2 Sin {C} Cos {C} +Sin {C}$
How could we solve this?